# How does Nature Shields Its Own work with "unblockable" and "can't be blocked"

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-archenemy

[Nature Shields Its Own](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=212577) is an archenemy card that allows you to place creature tokens on the battlefield blocking attacking creatures.  The rulings on its Gatherer page call out flying as an ability that this card bypasses, so does it also bypass "unblockable" and "can't be blocked"?

Are there any other cards that do that?

Comment: By the way, creatures that were "unblockable" were recently eratta'd to say "can't be blocked".

Comment: "Can't be blocked" means a blocker can't be assigned to this attacker. NSIO causes attackers to become blocked without doing defender assignments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the plant token blocks the creature even if that creature "can't be blocked". A ruling on Nature Shields Its Own's Gatherer page says

> The Plant token blocks the attacking creature **even if the block couldn't legally be declared** (for example, if the attacking creature has flying).

We can find other cards that do this by searching for the wording that Nature Shields Its Own uses: "onto the battlefield blocking". According to [this magiccards.info search](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22onto%20the%20battlefield%20blocking%22&v=card&s=cname), there are 3 cards that do this: [Ætherplasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=%C3%86therplasm), [Brimaz, King of Oreskos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Brimaz%2C%20King%20of%20Oreskos), and [Flash Foliage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flash%20Foliage).

Comment: I would say that out of those 3, Flash Foliage is the only one that uses the mechanic to get around `can't be blocked` since with the other two you already have to be able to block the creature.

Comment: In the case of Ætherplasm, Ætherplasm has to be able to block the creature, but the creature that comes into play may not be able to block it. This is also possible with Brimaz, if for example something gives him flying.

Comment: Chocking Vines, Curtain of Light, Dazzling Beauty and Trap Runner can also be used to block "can't be blocked" creatures

Comment: *Choking Vines. I also found Fog Patch. And Balduvian Warlord's ability